Azure functions v2 and python imports
I have a python project that works locally and has different functions split into different files based on their overall purpose. I'm trying to convert this to an Azure function v2, and I'm getting this error when I try to import my functions.
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
I've tried using
from . import say_hi With the following file structure,
/
- .functignore
- .gitignore
- function_app.py
- host.json
- local.settings.json
- requirements.txt
- test.py

And changing the file structure to
/
- .functignore
- .gitignore
- function_app.py
- host.json
- local.settings.json
- requirements.txt
/test
  - __init__.py
  - test.py

And then using
from .test import say_hi  and from test import say_hi
Is it possible to import functions from other files in azure functions?
test.py contains the following:
def say_hi():
    print("Hi")


The directory name 'test' and file name 'test' are predefined names. Therefore, you need to rename the directory or file names to successfully import packages and run the code.

If test.py is inside a folder, the folder name should not be test.

If test.py is in the same directory without a folder, you need to use a different name for the file.


Below is the V2 Azure Function model code to import functions from other files in the Azure Functions.
Code :
function_app.py :
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from test1.test import say_hi

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger")
@app.route(route="hello", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    say_hi()
    
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello from Azure Functions", status_code=200)

test1/test.py :
def say_hi():
    print("Hi from test.py")

Another Approach :
You can also use the code below to add the root directory to sys.path to find the 'test' module.
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from test.test import say_hi

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger")
@app.route(route="hello", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    say_hi()
    
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello from Azure Functions", status_code=200)

test/test.py :
def say_hi():
    print("Hi from test.py")

Output :
The following code ran successfully as shown below.

Browser Output :

